# add read more to subpage display automatecly in parent page

Tags: php, wordpress

i have made a parent page in wordpress and now i want all my subpage under the parent will apper in it 
so i use this code who works great only i cant get the read more to work 
this is the code i use 
help will be greatfull :)
' $post->ID, 'sort_column' => 'post_date', 'sort_order' => 'desc' ) );

```
foreach( $mypages as $page ) {      
    $content = $page->post_content;
    if ( ! $content ) // Check for empty page
        continue;

    $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
?>
    <h2><a href="<?php echo get_page_link( $page->ID ); ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></a></h2>
    <div class="entry"><?php echo $content; ?></div>
<?php
}
```

?>'

Comment: I'm not sure what question you're asking. Could you elaborate?

Comment: yes the site didnt let me paste all the code

Comment: i have a parent page 
under it i have subpages 
i want to display them with read more in the parent page

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a the_permalink(); with a 'read more'. E.g.

```
foreach( $mypages as $page ) {      
    $content = $page->post_content;
    if ( ! $content ) // Check for empty page
        continue;

    $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
?>
    <h2><a href="<?php echo get_page_link( $page->ID ); ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></a></h2>
    <div class="entry"><?php echo $content; ?></div>
    <div class="read_more"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">Read More..</a></div>
<?php
}   
?>
```

Comment: <?php
 $mypages = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID, 'sort_column' => 'post_date', 'sort_order' => 'desc' ) );

 foreach( $mypages as $page ) {  
  $content = $page->post_content;
  if ( ! $content ) // Check for empty page
   continue;

  $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
 ?>
  <h2><a href="<?php echo get_page_link( $page->ID ); ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></a></h2>
  <div class="entry"><?php echo $content; ?></div>
              <div class="read_more"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">Read More..</a></div>
 <?php
 } 
?>

Comment: i have inserted the code you wrote here but i dont get it to work

Comment: if i press the read more link it leads me back to parent page